# Select observations by date per ID

Tags: r, date

I would like to select observations by individual time ranges - my simulated data may explain, what I need:

There are two data frames:

- event_data: contains individuals (persons) who experience an event on
  a certain date. Every event is a new row, but an individual
  (identified by "event_person_id" may also experience more than one
  event (maybe 2, 3, 4, 5,...).
- visit_data: contains all personal contacts with individuals. Every
  visit is assigned to an individual ("visit_person_id") and has its
  own visit_date. There are far more visits than events.

Visit_data contains more data than I need in the end, because I only want to select those rows in visit_data, which occur in the time range between **"event_date" plus two years**.

**For example:** Person_id 1 has two events - the first on March 21st 2014 and the second on August 8th 2018, so I would like to select only those rows in visit_data which date between March 21st 2014 and March 21st 2016 as well as between August 8th 2018 and August 8th 2020.

My idea was to join event_data and visit_data by person_id - so I have a new data frame which contains visit_date as well as event_date and then I could select the relevant information, but my method is not completely correct as it (randomly?) assigns the first or the second event_date to the visit rows, f.e. **person_id 5** has a visit on 1988-12-15 but has the event_date of 2019-09-03 instead of 1988-03-04 and so this visit is ignored, because 2019 is not in the range of 1988 to 1990.

**If my idea of joining the tables is completely wrong or if there is a smarter way I would like to learn this better method!**

Here is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(123)

event_data <- data.frame(event_person_id = seq(1, 100, 1),
                         event_date = sample(seq(as.Date('1980/01/01'), as.Date('2010/12/31'), by="day"), 100),
                         age = round(runif(100, min = 1, max = 80)), 
                         bmi = round(runif(100, min = 19, max = 30)), 
                         amount = round(runif(100, min = 10, max = 10000)), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

event_data2 <- data.frame(event_person_id = seq(1, 10, 1),
                         event_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2011/01/01'), as.Date('2020/12/31'), by="day"), 10),
                         age = round(runif(10, min = 1, max = 80)), 
                         bmi = round(runif(10, min = 19, max = 30)), 
                         amount = round(runif(10, min = 10, max = 10000)), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

event_data_total <- rbind(event_data, event_data2)

visit_data <- data.frame(visit_person_id = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 100)),
                         visit_id = seq(1, 10000, 1),
                         visit_date = sample(seq(as.Date('1980/01/01'), as.Date('2020/12/31'), by="day"), 10000),
                         var1 = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 500)), 
                         var2 = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 1000)), 
                         var3 = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 9000)), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data_joined <-
  dplyr::inner_join(visit_data, event_data_total, by = c('visit_person_id' = 'event_person_id')) %>% 
  arrange(visit_date)

data_joined_final <- data_joined %>%
  filter(visit_date > event_date & visit_date < (event_date %m+% years(2)))
```

I would really be thankful for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly new at helping so have mercy ;) But as far as I understand you, a solution could come from the "data.table" "foverlaps". Which joins by overlapping dates and ID. I'm not 100% sure how exactly you would like your final data, but here comes a suggestion, that you can perhaps modify to your specific need.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)


set.seed(123)

event_data <- data.frame(event_person_id = seq(1, 100, 1),
                         event_date = sample(seq(as.Date('1980/01/01'), as.Date('2010/12/31'), by="day"), 100),
                         age = round(runif(100, min = 1, max = 80)), 
                         bmi = round(runif(100, min = 19, max = 30)), 
                         amount = round(runif(100, min = 10, max = 10000)), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

event_data2 <- data.frame(event_person_id = seq(1, 10, 1),
                          event_date = sample(seq(as.Date('2011/01/01'), as.Date('2020/12/31'), by="day"), 10),
                          age = round(runif(10, min = 1, max = 80)), 
                          bmi = round(runif(10, min = 19, max = 30)), 
                          amount = round(runif(10, min = 10, max = 10000)), 
                          stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

event_data_total <- rbind(event_data, event_data2)

visit_data <- data.frame(visit_person_id = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 100)),
                         visit_id = seq(1, 10000, 1),
                         visit_date = sample(seq(as.Date('1980/01/01'), as.Date('2020/12/31'), by="day"), 10000),
                         var1 = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 500)), 
                         var2 = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 1000)), 
                         var3 = round(runif(10000, min = 1, max = 9000)), 
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


#create the end dates + 2 years
event_data_total$end_date <- event_data_total$event_date + years(2)

#set as data.table
DT1 <- data.table(visit_data)
DT2 <- data.table(event_data_total)

#set joining keys
setkey(DT2, event_person_id, event_date, end_date)

#create dublicate columns with the same names, used for foverlaps
DT1[, c("event_date", "end_date") := visit_date] 
DT1[, c("event_person_id") := visit_person_id] 

#join data
data_joined<-foverlaps(DT1, DT2)

# now you should be able to sort it with e.g.
dat <- data_joined[complete.cases(data_joined), ]
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry for my very late response - I was not able to test your solution earlier... It works - thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem, glad it was of use